# Difficult to replicate CSS issue - HTML link positioning/display

Tags: html, css, wordpress

**As a quick intro, I'm not sure what the best way to phrase/tag/etc this question is, especially as it's so not really reproducible so I would appreciate any input from the stackoverflow community.**

On a couple of different WordPress websites I help manage, I occasionally see HTML link elements overflow their normal inline position - the link text overlaps any text after it, almost like the link is absolutely positioned. However, the links are statically positioned and inline as normal.

The big problem with this is that it's not consistent and I've not been able to reproduce the problem. This makes debugging and tracking very difficult. I work mostly in Chrome on Windows 7/10 but I have had reports from clients seeing it in IE and occasionally in Firefox (all on Windows I believe).

In addition, when I have been able to use the Chrome developer tools to debug this, the problem resolves itself if the browser window is resized or if almost **any** link css properties are changed. It's as if the browser draws the page wrong the first time and when it's forced to redraw the elements, it does it right the second time.

Is anyone else seeing this problem? Does anyone have any ideas what would be causing this and why it would be so inconsistent?

I've not been able to get a screengrab of the issue happening as it's not possible to replicate but I may update this question if I manage to capture it happening any time soon.

Comment: Have you got any jQuery being run on the page that deals with page height, or element height or widths?

Comment: @Lee - Almost definitely. I'm using parent themes for these sites and, while I haven't exactly read through every file to be able to confirm this, they do load a few of their own jQuery scripts.

Comment: Have you inspected the pages? When you hover over the elements, and they highlight on the page, do they appear okay there?

Comment: @Lee IIRC when I inspect the elements, the highlighted position appears slightly offset to the actual position of the links themselves. The text still overlaps both the actual link and it's highlighted "position".

Comment: Is this related to a specific theme you use for your websites?

Comment: @vard A couple of the sites I've seen this on do share a parent theme - as I've said though, it's difficult to replicate and easy to miss. Can't remember if it's happened on other sites but it's certainly possible.

Comment: A possible explanation for this kind of behaviour would be an early event in javascript. Maybe some js is changing something on your links container but is fired too early (before window.load), and miscalculate some width because some elements (images for instance) are not yet loaded. The fact that the problem is inconsistent could be then explained by the browser cache. Try to reload the page with an empty cache (ctrl+f5 on firefox) and see if it happens everytime. Though it'll be hard to troubleshoot for us without a live example.

Comment: One other good thing to do would be to try to load the page with JS disabled (if it doesn't break everything) and see if the problem still occurs.